# Formatting data in PowerShell

Tags: powershell

I am trying to read the data and write it into a .txt file using PowerShell.

But the in the result it get trimmed.

```
#Get the photo path of the students 
$commandAD = $connection.CreateCommand()

#Retrieving student photo records.
$commandAD.CommandText = "SELECT [Barcode],[ImageURL]   FROM 
[iSAMS_Custom].[dbo].[vwDestinyLibrary_Student_photo1]"
$resultPhoto = $commandAD.ExecuteReader()
$tablePhoto = new-object "System.Data.DataTable"
$tablePhoto.Load($resultPhoto)

#Export Hash Table to Txt File
$tablePhoto | Out-File c:\Users\nimmy.pk\Documents\inputphoto.txt
```

How I can format the data?

Comment: Maybe save it as a csv, it seems like the object is a table

Comment: I need the result as in txt format

Answer (score 2):

You can use the -Width parameter from Out-File:

```
$tablePhoto | Out-File -Width 4096 -Path c:\Users\nimmy.pk\Documents\inputphoto.txt
```

Comment: now the url showing completely, but all the results showing in a single column rather than in two.

Comment: I tried to delete the blank spaces between the columns but it doesn't work :( ... I am quite new to PowerShell and recently started learning. Anyone can help on the formatting of the output file to see the full result???

Comment: The use a CSV like @guiwhatsthat mentioned, $tablePhoto | Export-CSV -delimiter "`t" -path c:\Users\nimmy.pk\Documents\inputphoto.txt